# Change CSS class on hover Jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I feel like this is something so small and simple but I have been at it for an hour and I can't get it to work.

I simply want to change the background-color of the "right" div when the "left" div is hovered using jQuery.

My HTML:

```
<div id="left">Left</div>
<div id="right">Right</div>
```

My jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#left').hover(function () {
        $('#right').css("background-color", "#FFF");
    });
});
```

I have a JS Fiddle going: http://jsfiddle.net/MzTf6/2/

Please save me :)

Comment: Seems to work fine if you remember to include jQuery http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/MzTf6/3/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the OP forgot to include jQuery.

Comment: Why use JQuery if you can do that with pure CSS - [example](http://jsfiddle.net/NHzPa/)

Comment: Ugh...I knew it was something sooo stupid! @Vucko - how do you change the color of a different div on hover?  I know how to change the current div on hover...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working alright, but it seems that Jquery is not included.
Did you remember to add Jquery to your localhost code as well (if you have any)?

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Your JSFiddle with Jquery enabled.
http://jsfiddle.net/MzTf6/5/

Answer (score 1):

Well probably because in your fiddle your are not adding jQuery so if you trace your console yo should notice that the objects has no method $. On the other side, probably is not working because .hover() accepts two function: one for the mouseenter and one for the mouseleave event. I leave you this jsFiddle to check it out http://jsfiddle.net/MzTf6/6/. This is the code i used :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#left').hover(function () {
        $('#right').css("background", "red");
    }, function(){
        $('#right').css("background", "#000000");
    });
});
```